# Kubuntu 20.04 randomly does not load plasmashell. Where to start troubleshooting?

Tags: kubuntu, thinkpad, 20.04, plasma-5

New installation of Kubuntu 20.04. This is a Lenovo ThinkPad T460 that was running Kubuntu 19.10 for the last 6 months with no issues. The system has the following configuration:

- 16 GB RAM
- 1 TB SATA SSD
- EFI boot loader
- LVM with system installed in `ext4` logical volume for `/`
- Two users: `admin` and `myuser`. `myuser` is the main user
- `myuser` home folder resides in separate ZFS partition. `admin` in root partition

I've done some searching and I haven't come across reports of bugs that sound like they're the same.

The long story: This is a clean installation of Kubuntu 20.04 from a fresh download, downloaded using their torrent. The checksum matches.

Of the two users, `myuser` has its home folder in ZFS, whereas `admin` has it as default in the `ext4` root logical volume. Logging into either user often results in `plasmashell` either crashing or not loading properly. The result is a black desktop with a panel and `latte-dock`, but the desktop is unresponsive. I have attached a screenshot of the black screen below (top screenshot). Right-clicking on the desktop accomplishes nothing, whereas right-clicks on the panel and dock work fine.

I'm fairly certain that ZFS is not the issue, as both users are experiencing this bug. Ocasionally everything loads properly and I have a usable system.

Edit 1: Curiously, if I screenshot the whole desktop, it reproduces the black screen just as it is. However, if I screenshot the active window (second screenshot below), it shows me my proper desktop, so it's evidently there somewhere and just non-functional.

Edit 2: I can get a working desktop by running `kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell`. Needless to say this is a pretty crappy workaround.

Any thoughts?

Whole desktop screenshot:
[image: plasmashell does not load properly, resulting in a black desktop]

Active window screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I have a very similar issue. Only that I do not even have a panel, only the cursor. Taking a screenshot works, but I couldn't restart the Plasma with your workaround. Do you have a dual monitor setup? For me it seems that it could relate to it.

Comment: I have a clean 20.04 kubuntu install on a new Carbon X1 Exteme gen 2 and about once a day plasmashell locks and needs a killall/restart to restore. I notice when the clock stops - any proper fix most most welcome!

Comment: @Moha yes I do have a 2-monitor setup. I'll see what happens when I disconnect one, thanks for the lead!

Comment: For me, the culprit was automatic mounting. I have a bunch of HDDs and they were set to automount on login. As soon as I switched the automount off in KDE settings, the issue gone and Plasma loads normally. I think I will just add the mounting in fstab.

Comment: I narrowed down the issue to the use of a dock and external monitor. Ubuntu was randomly not drawing a desktop on the external monitor. Disconnecting the laptop from the dock, then reconnecting it fixes the issue. I suspect a bug in the handling of external monitors.

Comment: I also get this with Kubuntu 22.04 and an external monitor. Also, whenever I click the desktop, click gets redirected to the last active window. Finally, if I type after minimizing all windows, the keys get redirected to KRunner. However, when I screenshot the "active window" but select the desktop, the wallpaper is shown in the screenshot. Wierd.